# Manually update specific html elements in a blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I'm learning blazor by building a client side web application.

I made a loop that increments a number every 10 ms and by calling `StateHasChanged` my component is re-rendered every loop. I also have a progress bar but I only want to re-render it every second for performance gains.

Can I do that?
Or am I going about this in a wrong way?

Code samples for context:

```
    <div>
        <span>Count = @Count / @Max</span>
        <br />
        <span>Percent = @Percent</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: @Percent%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

@code {

    public int Max { get; set; } = 500;
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Percent => (int)(100 * (double)Count / (double)Max);
    public bool IsRunning { get; protected set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Task.Run(() => Loop());
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    public async Task Loop()
    {
        if (IsRunning) return;
        IsRunning = true;

        while (IsRunning && Count < Max)
        {
            Count++;
            StateHasChanged();

            // ~every second
            if (Count % 100 == 0)
            {
                // re-render the progress bar
            }
            await Task.Delay(10); // ~loop duration in ms
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were ***VERY*** close, just need to rearrange your `OnInitializedAsync` method a little bit and move your percent logic into the loop. Note below that the `OnInitializedAsync` is now marked with `async` so you can await your loop function instead of starting a task. I only show items below that I changed.

```cs
public int Percent { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await Loop();
    // Don't need a call to base here, 
    // in base it's just a stub to satisfy 
    // the original call from the Blazor framework. 
}

public async Task Loop()
{
    if (IsRunning)
        return;
    IsRunning = true;
    while (IsRunning && Count < Max)
    {
        Count++;
        // ~every second
        if (Count % 100 == 0)
        {
            Percent = (int)(100 * (double)Count / (double)Max);
        }
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(10); // ~loop duration in ms
    }
    
    IsRunning = false;
}
```

Since `Loop` is an awaitable task, it will kick off but the rest of the DOM will render, and then every time it hits `StateHasChanged()` it will re-render. Since the casting for the percentage calc is now in the loop and only runs at intervals, it is a bit cheaper on the casting, but the DOM still refreshes every time. Blazor is designed to make the DOM diff as small as possible so you shouldn't get hit that hard at all.

I fired this up in a new Blazor Server app with the changes mentioned and it worked like a charm.